# magento 2: exception error

Tags: magento2, exception

I am working on the theme and today i noticed that the search result page is broken.

This is the Exception captured:

```
            1 exception(s):
            Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'remove': This element is not expected.
            Line: 782


            Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'remove': This element is not expected.
            Line: 782

            #0 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
            #1 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/home/r2gutenb/...', '%message%\nLine:...')
            #2 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
            #3 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
            #4 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
            #5 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(141): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
            #6 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
            #7 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
            #8 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
            #9 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
            #10 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
            #11 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
            #12 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(207): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
            #13 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild()
            #14 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(114): Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayoutUpdates()
            #15 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Controller/Result/Index.php(91): Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout()
            #16 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Controller/Result/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index->execute()
            #17 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->execute()
            #18 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #19 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
            #20 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #21 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Controller/Result/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
            #22 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #23 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #24 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
            #25 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #26 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #27 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #28 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #29 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #30 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
            #31 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
            #32 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
            #33 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
            #34 /home/r2gutenb/public_html/index.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
            #35 {main}
```

Comment: did u added any custom xml file for search?

Comment: my problem is that i checked all the xmls i added and i can't find any "remove"

Comment: how can i read this Exception to find it?

Comment: Seems like you are using remove in your xml file which is causing the issue, try to comment that out.